# Bash Division and Modulus

Tags: bash, sh

I have a problem getting the following (tried multiple varians with $, (), backticks `, etc...) to work:

```
GetAmountOfFileBlocks()
{
        export DOC_BLOCKS=0
        DOC_BLOCKS= $(`expr $DOCS_AMOUNT / $CHUNK_AMOUNT`)
        DIVISOR=echo expr  $DOCS_AMOUNT % $CHUNK_AMOUNT
        if [ $DIVISOR -ne "0" ]
        then
                $DOC_BLOCKS=$DOC_BLOCKS+1;
        fi
}
```

In debug (with -x) it shows as something like this:

> - export DOC_BLOCKS=0
> - DOC_BLOCKS=0
>     ++ expr 193 / 64
> - DOC_BLOCKS=
> - 3 ./cnv_dm_assign_files_to_chunks.sh: line 87: 3: command not found
> - DIVISOR=echo
> - expr 193 % 64

I need to get a number that would represent the number of blocks needed to accomodate the given divisor (in this example, 193/64 would mean 3 and a reminder, meaning I need 4 "blocks" for my purposes.

Comment: So which is it? `bash` or `sh`? They are two different things.

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: @SeanBright: I was reading about the differences, and from my understanding, today they are essentially the same thing for all intents and purposes. In some systems sh is alias to bash.

Comment: @Carmageddon, unfortunately they are not essentially the same thing. There are features provided by `bash` (colloquially referred to as "bashisms") that are not available in all shells. If you're striving for portability, you should use a `#!/bin/sh` shebang and validate your scripts with shellcheck.net as @Cyrus points out.

Comment: @Cyrus: Thank you very much! using shellcheck.net pointed out all my errors! If you had an answer, would have accepted it as you were first... Thumbs up!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
DOC_BLOCKS=$(( DOCS_AMOUNT / CHUNK_AMOUNT ))
REMAINDER=$(( DOCS_AMOUNT % CHUNK_AMOUNT ))

if [ "$REMAINDER" -gt "0" ]
then
  DOC_BLOCKS=$(( DOC_BLOCKS + 1 ))
fi
```

Comment: Why did you change to -gt 0 instead of original? performance reason? easy reading?

Comment: What about the quotes? "0" vs 0, what is the difference in this case?

Comment: That's a good question. I've never been sure about that distinction. I've updated my answer based on what I've seen to be the prevailing idiom.

Comment: Normal bash would be `if (( REMAINDER )); then ((DOC_BLOCKS++); fi` or even `(( DOC_BLOCKS += REMAINDER > 0 ))`. But you could avoid the whole issue by doing the computation correctly at the beginning: `declare -i DOC_BLOCKS=(DOCS_AMOUNT+CHUNK_AMOUNT-1)/CHUNK_AMOUNT`

Comment: @rici, are there similar shortcuts for POSIX `sh`?

Comment: The `(( ... ))` arithmetic compound command is not required by Posix, but Posix recognizes that many shells do implement it. The `$((...))` arithmetic substitution is Posix standard, and you can use the `:` statement in order to execute arithmetic operations. Eg: `: $((DOC_BLOCKS=(DOCS_AMOUNT+CHUNK_AMOUNT-1)/CHUNK_AMOUNT))` is completely Posix standard. (But honestly, if you have bash, you might as well use it, IMHO). PD: Using all-caps variable names is strongly discouraged in any shell script.